# Hide a variable-width element off to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following layout: **http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2487/**

What I need to do is hide the `.hidden` class to the right edge of the `.block` class and have it only appear (by sliding in) on hover to the current position you see it in the JSFiddle.

The issue is, the `.hidden` class is of variable-width, meaning that the content inside it (`ABCDEFGHIJKL`) can be completely different, sometimes shorter, sometimes longer.

How would I solve this?

**Edit:** To clarify what I mean by hiding it to the right edge of the `.block` class, I mean [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg44M.png), except it wouldn't be shown.

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="hidden">ABCDEFGHIJKL</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.block .hidden {
    background: red;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: To solve my own question, I simply removed `right: 0` from `.block .hidden` and put `left: 100%`. http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2488/

Answer (score 1):

To solve my own question, I simply removed `right: 0` from `.block .hidden` and put `left: 100%`.

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/2488

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="hidden">ABCDEFGHIJKL</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightgrey;
}

.block .hidden {
    background: red;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```